# How to speed-up the time waiting for my unicorn to finish its race?

Tags: secret-of-the-magic-crystals

In "Secret of the Magic Crystals", I try to earn some money by signing my unicorn in races. My problem is I have to wait for 35 seconds for each race, and there is no interactivity during this event. Is there a way to speed things up?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/y8yN5.jpg]

Comment: Pick up a good book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several horses can run at the same time. Plus, you can train a horse while another races. Unfortunately, it is impossible to speed-up the time and would be considered a design flaw.